# Is it safe to use a folded evap/vacuum line?

Tags: parts, evap, vacuum

I recieved a my new evap purge valve (for a 2015 ford edge sport) and it came with a major kink in the line. Is this still safe to use or will the line be damaged inside? I cannot separate it from the other parts to inspect it

[image]

Answer (score 0):

"Is it safe to use a folded evap/vacuum line?"

No its not, They need to have high flow, either return it for another or use a heat gun on low to straighten it out and make it round again

Comment: If the heat gun doesn't make it right, remove it and replace with a high quality rubber hose (ask for fuel line @ local autoparts store.)  You can also add hose clamps.  Inexpensive fix.  A lot depends on where you bought it... a high quality auto parts store will warranty an improper storage crimp like this.